# EntityFramework Core - How to set Column Description

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I've read the docs, browsed the source and applied my Google and Bing Foo but can not determine
How to set the description on a SQL column using EF Core Code First.

Thanks

I try with no exit:
[image: code]
[image: result]

**I try to put in here but not working:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
         modelBuilder.Entity<Report>()
              .Property(e => e.ReportType)
              .HasComment("Trip = 0, Temperature = 1, Event = 2");
      }
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're using the right code. Can you show a wider view of the code?

Comment: How did you apply migrations to the database after adding `HasComment()` method?

Comment: What net version are you running ?

Comment: you must use migration command. Did you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the HasComment method as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.hascomment?view=efcore-3.1) and **run it once the table is already on the DB**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Report>()
    .Property(e => e.ReportType)
    .HasComment("Report Type Description");
```

Comment: Hello. Wich event is it? I put in here:  `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`

Comment: right there thats the correct method